# Cookies on IE6 Standalone on Windows server 2003?

Tags: internet-explorer-6, internet-explorer-7, compatibility

I cant seem to get IE6 and IE7 running alongside each other on my Windows Server 2003 VPC.

I have tried both: http://browsers.evolt.org/?ie/32bit/standalone
and: http://tredosoft.com/Multiple_IE , and yes, I tried putting the Wininet.dll in my standalone path.

The browser works, but cookies does not! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also, I am aware of the VPC Microsoft has supplied, but i am trying to avoid that solution as well, since I am developing on another VPC (and this is not something thats about to change, one reason being that these VPCs are time-limited), and I would like to keep the benefits of developing on the same machine I am testing on, ie: I dont want to redeploy my entire solution every time I want to check my updates.

Comment: Do cookies work if you test from a distinct user account for each browser version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of those methods are hacks and not guaranteed to work. You may be missing things in your testing due to unknown side-effects.  Why not just use the VPC as explained in this article: [IE6 and IE7 Running on a Single Machine](http://www.testingreflections.com/node/view/4673).